# There's a private Class "P" in A.java ("P" uses some methods in A.java), how can B.java access "P"?

Tags: java

Ok, I have a `private class MyClickHandler` in Order.java. I want Customer.java to be able to use `MyClickHandler`, but I don't want to copy the exact code of `private class MyClickHandler` to B.java.

However, the problem is that `MyClickHandler` also uses some methods in Order.java. Luckily, these methods also needs to be used in Customer.java.

Order.java

```
public class Order{
    private class MyClickHandler implements ClickHandler{
        CheckBox myCheckBox;
        MyTextColumn myTextColumn;
        public MyClickHandler(CheckBox myCheckBox, MyTextColumn myTextColumn){
            this.myCheckBox=myCheckBox;
            this.myTextColumn=myTextColumn;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(myCheckBox.getValue()){
                insertColumn(myTextColumn);
            }
        }
     }
     public void insertColumn(MyTextColumn myTextColumn){
         // This method is also called by other methods in Order.java
     }
     public void removeColumn(MyTextColumn myTextColumn){
         // This method is also called by other methods in Order.java
     }

}
```

Now I want Customer.java to use `MyClickHandler`. Besides, it also needs to use methods `insertColumn` & `removeColumn`

Comment: Does it *have* to be a private class? You could make Order a public or package-protected class in a separate java file, so it's accessible to both. https://www.google.com/search?q=package+protected+java

Comment: Order.java & Customer.java

Comment: Yes, we can make MyClickHandler to be public, but how we can bring 2 methods insertColumn & removeColumn with it?

Comment: the file is Order.java so we call Order class

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what this is supposed to be doing it's hard to clean up the design fully, but as a start I would do something like this:

1. Make all the classes `public`
2. Extract the common behaviour of
   `Order` and `Customer` into a superclass (named `Parent` below - bad
   name!)
3. Just instantiate an instance of `MyClickHandler` in for
   example, `Order`, and pass a reference to `this` to it so you can
   call methods on it in the same way as you would if it were a private
   class.

---

```
public class Parent {

   public void insertColumn(MyTextColumn myTextColumn){
      // implement
   }

   public void removeColumn(MyTextColumn myTextColumn){
      // implement
   }
}

public class Order extends Parent{

    ClickHandler clickHandler;       

    public ClickHandler getClickHandler(CheckBox myCheckBox, MyTextColumn myTextColumn) {
         return new MyClickHandler(this, myCheckBox, myTextColumn);
    }

}

public class Customer extends Parent {

//similar to Order

}

public class MyClickHandler implements ClickHandler {

    private CheckBox myCheckBox;
    private MyTextColumn myTextColumn;
    private Parent parent;

    public MyClickHandler(Parent parent, CheckBox myCheckBox, MyTextColumn myTextColumn){
        this.parent = parent;
        this.myCheckBox = myCheckBox;
        this.myTextColumn = myTextColumn;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(myCheckBox.getValue()){
            parent.insertColumn(myTextColumn);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you've got an interesting mix of logic which makes sense to be pulled out by

- **Inheritance** - in the case of the methods that you want implemented the same in both Order and Customer i.e. common behaviour which conceptually belongs to those classes and therefore  makes sense to be implemented as generic behaviour in a superclass
- **Composition** - as in the ClickHandler implementation that you want to use in both places - this is a totally conceptually separate module of logic which should be pulled out into its own class and just used by the other two.

Comment: Can we make Parent like Utility class & make all methods insertColumn & removeColumn to be static?

Comment: Class inheritance still hasn't been outlawed? I'd definitely opt for composition and delegation instead of creating yet another class hierarchy.

Comment: @ Denis, so we put insertColumn & removeColumn into Utility class or we extends Parent like davnicwil's solution? or Do u have any other solution?

Comment: @Tum you can pretty much do what you want, and make it work - this is really about how to extract logic in the cleanest way given the constructs Java gives us - doing the above is just one suggestion - but I definitely think it's cleaner than using static utility methods which are almost always evil :-)

Comment: @ Denis, why static method in Utility class is evil?

Comment: @DennisTraub I added a little bit about that at the end - obviously it's a debate that could be had, potentially composition is the best way to pull out this common logic too, I couldn't possibly tell without more detail. Just thought I'd highlight the use of both approaches, pros and cons are always case-specific I'd say

Comment: @Tum that's another debate entirely, but for one, static methods don't lend themselves to unit testing

Comment: @davnicwil You're right. Unfortunately there is no cookie cutter approach.

Comment: @ davnicwil, i forgot to tell U that Order.java already extending a Class so I can't make it extends other classes, can u modify ur code? maybe using Interfaces or something

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public method that either creates a new instance of MyClickHandler or returns an already existing one.

I wouldn't advise this though, i feel like a package-protected class would be a better solution.